# Change value of variable on checkbox checked rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am new to rails. Please help me as I do not have clear knoledge on usage of jquery and ajax in rails.

I am having a checkbox for tasks. I have a boolean field is_completed in my database which is set to false by default. when checkbox is checked the value of is_completed should be set to true and if unchecked it should be false.

migration for tasks table

```
  t.boolean :is_completed, :default => false
```

my view code is

```
  <%= check_box_tag :is_completed %>
```

in my task.js

```
  $(':checkbox').change(function() {
     if (this.checked) {
   alert('completed')
      /* is_completed should be true */
     } 
     else {
  /* is_completed should be true */
    } 
   });
 });
```

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Can you post the whole view code and the roots? Are you hoping to do this via ajax, its not stated anywhere.

Comment: What else can he do except ajax?

Comment: make form for each object with remote:true, so rails will take care about everything. Its bad way, but easiest.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() { 
    var checked = $(':checkbox').prop('checked');
    if (checked)
        alert('yes');   
    else
        alert('no');
});
```

Comment: It did not work. I want the field in my data base to be changed to true. if check box is checked but even if I check the checkbox no response

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475507/how-to-access-jquerys-ajax-call-in-ror)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery ajax:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
   $.ajax({
    url: "/tasks/" + task_id,
    data: "&task[is_completed]=" + this.checked,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "PUT"
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a method and passed the value from jquery and using ajax request got the things done.

In task.js

```
  $(function () {
    $(':checkbox').change(function () {
      var task_id = jQuery('#task_id:hidden').val();
      complete_task(task_id);
   });


 function complete_task(task_id) {
$.ajax({    
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "html",
  url: "/tasks/"+task_id+"/complete_task",
  data: {"task_id": task_id},
  success: function(data) {
    $("#task_status").html(data);
  }
 });
 }
});
```

in tasks_controller

```
 def complete_task
@task =Task.find(params[:task_id])
@task.is_completed = true
@task.save
render :partial => 'task'
end
```